# Excel VBA loop throws out the last loop answer as answer to every loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I just can't this to give me the correct answers! I am trying to import values for temperatures from 1 excel sheet - "Design" - to another excel sheet - "Design2". If a combobox's text is "C" - the temperature value should be just as it is. If the combobox is on "K", 273.15 should be added to the temperature value to convert it to kelvin.

This part works fine.

However, the program gives the same value for every temperature on the "Design2" sheet- even though the temperatures on the "design" sheet is different.

Can somebody please help???

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub OK_Click()
    'Temperature
    Dim Temperaturei As Double
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    For i = 201 To 218
        For j = 4 To 36 Step 2
            For k = 2 To 19
                Temperaturei = Sheets("Design").Cells(36, j).Value
                        Sheets("Design2").Cells(k, 2).Value = Temperaturei
                    Select Case Sheets("Diagram").TemperatureUnit.Text
                        Case "°C"
                            Temperaturei = Temperaturei
                        Case "K"
                            Temperaturei = Temperaturei + 273.15
                    End Select
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you meaning to iterate through Design and Design2 seperately?  Because the way your loops are set up right now your going to iterate through Design2 while only using one value from Design.  K will go from 2 to 19 while J stays at 4.  Then when J moves to 5, K will move from 2 to 19 again.  I'm not sure of the design of your program, but is that what you're trying to do?

If not, you should consider combining your second and third loops into one loop so that both sheets iterate at the same time.  I can see you need to step by 2 on "Design", but you can do that by simply saying something like ((k*2) + 2) to get the same effect.

Example:

```
Dim j as Integer
For k = 2 to 19
    j = (k*2) 'If k = 2, j = 4, if k = 3, j = 6, etc, etc.
    [Do stuff]

End For
```

I'm kind of shooting in the dark, but I think that may be your problem.  In fact, after reading your question one more time, I'm pretty sure this is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

What if you move the line:

`Sheets("Design2").Cells(k, 2).Value = Temperaturei`

to just before

`Next k`

That way you will write your `Temperaturei` result to the Design2 sheet after it's been altered by the code. The way its written now, it doesn't write the altered value anywhere, after picking it up from the `Design` sheet.

So, in full, your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
'Temperature
Dim Temperaturei As Double
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For i = 201 To 218
    For j = 4 To 36 Step 2
        For k = 2 To 19

            'pick up value
            Temperaturei = Sheets("Design").Cells(36, j).Value

                'alter it
                Select Case Sheets("Diagram").TemperatureUnit.Text
                    Case "°C"
                        Temperaturei = Temperaturei
                    Case "K"
                        Temperaturei = Temperaturei + 273.15
                End Select

             'write back to sheet
             Sheets("Design2").Cells(k, 2).Value = Temperaturei

        Next k
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Chane -> for the benefit of those to come, it would be great if you mark 1 of the two answers as your chosen one, if they indeed helped you get what you were after. Or alternatively, post your own answer with your solution. Saying I fixed it, without showing how, is likely leading a horse to water, but not teaching him how to drink! Best to you...